# How to make a BST from a .txt file

Tags: python

This is my BST code:

```
class BinarySearchTree(BinaryTree):

def insert(self, value):
    parent = None
    x = self.root
    while(x):
        parent = x
        if value < x.data:
            x = x.left
        else:
            x = x.right
    if parent is None:
        self.root = Node(value)
    elif value < parent.data:
        parent.left = Node(value)
    else:
        parent.right = Node(value)

def search(self, value):
    return self._search(value, self.root)

def _search(self, value, node):
    if node is None:
        return node
    if node.data == value:
        return BinarySearchTree(node)
    if value < node.data:
        return self._search(value, node.left)
    return self._search(value, node.right)
```

and i want it to open a .txt file that have words like this

*apple
grape
banana
lemon*

and only show the first 4 levels

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code which reads it from file?

Comment: you can use standard `open()` `read()` `close()` to get it as single string, and later use `split(" ")` to convert to list of strings/words